# How to pass a variable through scope into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside an element `directive` named `tabset`, i am using element `directive` named `tab` twice which requires `tabset`.
I am doing a `console.log(attr.newvar)` from  `link` of `tabset`.
`newvar` is the value passed into the scope of the `tabset` directive.

So the `tabset` gets called 2 times (which i suppose is correct), and hence output is `console`d twice.

1st time, the `console` output is giving the correct output, but the 2nd time it is showing `newvar` as undefined .

but i am not able to access `newvar` through `scope.newvar`.In case of `console.log(scope.newvar)`, i get output as `undefined` twice.

Why is this happening ?

**HTML snippet**

```
<tabset newvar="black">
    <tab></tab>
    <tab></tab>
</tabset>
```

**JS snippet**

```
.directive('tab',function(){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    require:'^tabset',
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
        heading:"@"
    },
    template:'<div ng-show="active" ng-transclude></div>',
    link:function(scope,elem,attr,tabsetCtrl){
        scope.active = false;
        tabsetCtrl.add(scope);
    }
}
})
.directive('tabset',function(){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
        item:"=",
        newvar:"@"          
    },
    transclude:true,
    templateUrl:'/partials/tabset/tabset.html',
    bindToController:true,
    controllerAs:'tabset',
    controller:function($scope){

        var self = this;
        self.tabs = []
        self.add = function add(tab){
            self.tabs.push(tab);
            if(self.tabs.length === 1){
        tab.active = true;
        }
        }

        self.click = function click(selectedTab){
            angular.forEach(self.tabs,function(tab){
                 if(tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) 
                    tab.active = false;


        })
        selectedTab.active = true;
    }
},
link:function(scope,elem,attr,optionsCtrl){
        console.log(scope.newvar)
        scope.resetInput = function(){
            console.log("in resetInput")
            optionsCtrl.firstBox = "e"
            scope.item = "";
        }
        }
}
})
```

**tabset template**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-class="'{{newvar}}'" >
<li class='' ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" >
    <a href="" ng-click="tabset.click(tab);resetInput();" ng-class='{"tab-active":tab.active,"tab-inactive":tab.active === false}'> {{tab.heading}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ng-transclude>
</ng-transclude>
```

Comment: Ermm, `var` is a reserved word is javascript

Comment: that is not the name i have used, anyways question edited

Comment: @dreamer, it would be super helpful if you could give us more code samples. Specifically, I'd need to see your directive code.

Comment: @beaudetious: question  edited as per request

Comment: I believe you can change ng-class="'{{newvar}}'" to ng-class="newvar". This won't fix your issue but it will clean things up a bit.

Comment: I was wondering where the console.log(scope.newvar) was. ;)

Comment: @beaudetious:  some major editings done to the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77240/discussion-between-dreamer-and-beaudetious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `bindToController: true` you could access you controller scope from link function 4th parameter which is controller, which will give you access to the directive controller `this` which is using `controllerAs` syntax in it.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    console.log(ctrl.newvar);
    //ctrl.newvar = attr.newvar;
}
```

**Update**

As you want to add class to your `tab` `ul` element. I think you shouldn't use `ng-class` there. `ng-class` used when conditionally `show`/`hide` any class in html. You should use plane `{{}}` interpolation in you class attribute. While accessing scope variable you need to use `tabset.` because you are using `controllerAs` syntax with its alias. I tried to add class with `ng-attr-class` but the class gets added but other two classes was getting removed `nav nav tabs` that's the reason behind using `{{tabset.newvar}}`.

**Template**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs {{tabset.newvar}}">
    <li class='' ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" >
        <a href="" ng-click="tabset.click(tab);resetInput();" ng-class='{"tab-active":tab.active,"tab-inactive":tab.active === false}'> {{tab.heading}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/I71WaX0jyPvQClOrFWWt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope.tabset` to reference the controller and thereby give you access to your variable. Like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
    console.log(scope.tabset.newvar);
}
```

Comment: where do `scope.tabset` come from?

Comment: It is the controller object as in @pankajparkar's response above but I've just given you a different way of accessing it via the scope. You should probably go with his suggestion as it is a clearer way of doing it :-)

Comment: This looks like an appendix to the other answer, which is generally not the best idea. Rewrite to make it stand alone, if possible.