# Not able to access the variable within directive which is passed through scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

`tab` `directive` is used from within `tabset` `directive`.
 A variable `newvar` passed through `tabset` is not being able to be accessed in the `link` of `tabset`

A demo of this problem is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iLXqSnFtW9GjdfoE6CHf?p=preview) in plunkr

Why am i not able to access `newvar` through the `link` function
 ?

**HTML snippet**

```
     <tab heading="tab1">
        <p>This is tab1</p>
     </tab>
     <tab heading="tab2">
        <p>This is tab2</p>
     </tab>

  </tabset>
```

**JS snippet**

```
.directive('tabset',function(){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
        newvar:"@"          
    },
    transclude:true,
    templateUrl:'tabset.html',
    bindToController:true,
    controllerAs:'tabset',
    controller:function($scope){

        var self = this;
        self.tabs = []
        self.add = function add(tab){
            self.tabs.push(tab);
            if(self.tabs.length === 1){
        tab.active = true;
        }
        } 

        self.click = function click(selectedTab){
            angular.forEach(self.tabs,function(tab){
                 if(tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) 
                    tab.active = false;


        })
        selectedTab.active = true;

    }
}, 
  link:function(scope,elem,attr){

            console.log(scope.newvar);
            scope.newvar = attr.newvar;

  }
}
})
```

Comment: Can you add the tab directive as well?

Comment: @floribon this is duplicate..dreamer I think you have added this question twice...here I already gave an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30111413/2435473

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable through scope into directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109629/how-to-pass-a-variable-through-scope-into-directive)